# XmlSlurper to return all xml elements into a map

Tags: groovy

I have the following groovy code:

```
def xml = '''<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<foot>
    <email>m@m.com</email>
    <sig>hello world</sig>
</foot>
</note>'''

def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
```

How do I get records to return a map looks like the following:

```
["to":"Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder","body":"Don't forget me this weekend!","foot":["email":"m@m.com","sig":"hello world"]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what if in xml will be for example double tag <to>Jani</to> <to>Bani</to> coz in xml it is very possible?

Comment: It is a possible scenario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can swing the recursion weapon. ;)

```
def xml = '''<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<foot>
    <email>m@m.com</email>
    <sig>hello world</sig>
</foot>
</note>'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

def convertToMap(nodes) {
    nodes.children().collectEntries { 
        [ it.name(), it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text() ] 
    }
}

assert convertToMap( slurper ) == [
    'to':'Tove', 
    'from':'Jani', 
    'heading':'Reminder', 
    'body':"Don't forget me this weekend!", 
    'foot': ['email':'m@m.com', 'sig':'hello world']
]
```

Comment: why collect().sum() and not collectEntries() ?

Comment: In one line for a laugh: `def map = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).children().collectEntries {n->[(n.name()):{->n.children()?.collectEntries(owner)?:n.text()}()]}`

Comment: @tim_yates Cool. This is the second time I have seen you playing swiftly with `owner` here in SO. ;-) Both of them involved recursion. :P

Comment: @dmahapatro ...wracking my brains thinking of another valid use for `owner`... ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys :), but I ran your solution and saw the following exception: Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types: (CopyOftest$_run_closure1) values: [CopyOftest$_run_closure1@5c0ad75b]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types: (CopyOftest$_run_closure1) values: [CopyOftest$_run_closure1@5c0ad75b]
 at CopyOftest.run(CopyOftest.groovy:23)

Comment: How old is your version of groovy?

Comment: When I ran it in Eclipse (groovy compiler 2.1), it complaints with the above error. When I run it from command line (groovy compiler 2.3), it is working fine....

Comment: I used it in my code, but it seems to ignore multiple children and just adds one of them (looks like the second one of 2)

Comment: @RuthiRuth How does the xml look like?

Comment: @RuthiRuth I believe I have the idea what you are facing here. This is expected. A map cannot have duplicate keys. If you have notes which are repeated in XML then you have come up with a plan to represent them in a list.

Comment: yes I was thinking this could be the case, but wanted to point out that this is not a general solution - more a solution to a very specific problem (my question was marked as a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932850/transform-xml-into-a-map-using-groovy

Answer (score 0):

The posted solution works if you have unique tags among children of a node.
The problem with `collectEntries` is that it only allows unique keys. If you have `<to>Jani</to> <to>Bani</to>` the last tag will overwrite the previous one in the resulting Map. To avoid this you can group the children by their name first using `groupBy`.

```java
Map xmlToMap(node) {
    if( !node.childNodes() ){
        [(node.name()): node.text()]
    }else{
        Map groups = node.children().groupBy { it.name() }
        [(node.name()): groups.collectEntries { k, v ->
            v.size() == 1 ? xmlToMap(v.first()) : [k, v.collectMany { xmlToMap(it).values() }]
        }]
    }
}

def xml = '''<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<to>Jani</to> 
<to>Bani</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<foot>
    <email>m@m.com</email>
    <email>m2@m.com</email>
    <sig>hello world</sig>
</foot>
</note>'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
assert xmlToMap(slurper).note == [to:['Tove', 'Jani', 'Bani'], from:'Jani', heading:'Reminder', body:"Don't forget me this weekend!", foot:[email:['m@m.com', 'm2@m.com'], sig:'hello world']]
```