# Transform XML into a Map using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have some XML that I want to transform into a Map. I used the middle way of transforming XML to JSON and then greating a map of the json:

```
import org.json.XML
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
  Map parseXml(String input) {
    String json = XML.toJSONObject(input).toString()
    new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
  }
```

But when you have name spacing, it does not get removed.

eg.

```
<ns2:someObject xmlns:ns2="http://someLink">
  <someOtherObject>
    <something>SOME_THING</something>
  </someOtherObject>
  <someOtherObject>
    <something>SOME_THING_ELSE</something>
  </someOtherObject>
</ns2:someObject>
```

will end up in

```
{
  "ns2:someObject": {
    "xmlns:ns2": "http://someLink",
    "someOtherObject": [
      {
        "something": "SOME_THING"
      },
      {
        "something": "SOME_THING_ELSE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want it to end up like this:

```
{
  "someObject":  [
      {
        "something": "SOME_THING"
      },
      {
        "something": "SOME_THING_ELSE"
      }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can achive that without reinventing the wheel?

I already found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883223/xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map) a bit similar to mine, but it has a different approach, that's why I asked my question.
The example I gave is just an example, but there dan be multiple entries of `someObjects` which the given answer in the other post does not include.
Secondly it does iterate over the XML and creates a map of it - that is what I meant with `reinventing the wheel`. I am sure there must be a library doing exactly that already, so for me it seems wrong to write the parsing code myself.

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlSlurper to return all xml elements into a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883223/xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map)

Comment: I marked this is as a duplicate, as I believe the answer to the older question will work in this case.

Comment: As I said I wanted to believe that there is a parser already doing that for you as I do not want to reinvent the wheel. 

In addition I want it to be generic, so if I get a new xml attribute it should automatically be included and the generic answer in the other post does not include the root parent.