# Groovy: Create Object for add in LinkedHasMap

Tags: java, groovy

I novice in Groovy and Java.
I have function which returns LinkedHashMap from some Object. It works:

```
def get_map(Node) {
    nodeRootName = Node.name() 
    if (Node.childNodes().size() == 0) {
        return [(nodeRootName): (Node.text())]
    } else {
        subMap = [(nodeRootName):[]]
        for (subNode in Node.childNodes()) {
            if (subNode.name() != "cryptoSigns") {
                subMap.(subMap.keySet()[0]).add(get_map(subNode))
            }    
        }
        return subMap
    }
}
```

Call this function in code:

```
    nodeMap = [(rootNodeName): [data:[]]] 
    for (subNode in node.childNodes()[0].childNodes()) {
            nodeMap.position.data.add(get_map(subNode))
        }
    }
```

Array `[data:[]]` of LinkedHashMap is formed.

Now, I need from array make one LinkedHasMap.
I try make one map in my function. It can be one map or a map array with a key. For exmple:

```
[data:[
 key1: value,
 key2:[
   [key: value],
   [key: [
    [key: value],
    [key: value]
   ]
 ]
]]
```

I try:

```
def get_map(Node) {
    nodeRootName = Node.name() 
    if (Node.childNodes().size() == 0) {
        Map map = new HashMap()
        map.put((nodeRootName), (Node.text()))
        return map
    } else {
        Map subMap = new HashMap()
        for (subNode in Node.childNodes()) {
            subMap.put((nodeRootName), (get_map(subNode)))    
        }
        return subMap
    }
}
```

Call function:

```
 Map nodeMap = new HashMap()
 Map data = new HashMap()
 for (subNode in node.childNodes()[0].childNodes()) {
      data.put(get_map(subNode))
      nodeMap.put((rootNodeName): (data))
 }  
 jsonObject.nsiKTRUs.add(nodeMap)
```

But I have error: 
*groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.put() is applicable for argument types: (HashMap) values: [[code:01.11.11.111-00001]]* at `data.put(get_map(subNode))`

How correct add my values in map?
My input data:

```
<xml>
 <data>
   <key>value</key>
     <key2>
       <key21>value</key>
       <key22>value</key>
       <key23>
         <key231>value</key>
       </key>
    </key2>
 </data>
<xml>
```

Custom embedding.

Need output

```
[data:[
    key: value, 
    key2:[
        key21: value, 
        key22: value, 
        key23:[
          key231: value
        ]
     ]
 ]
]
```

and output data need add to another LinkedHashMap

Comment: it really hurts to read that "code" up there... can you simply show the input data and desired output?

Comment: input: `<xml><data><key>value</key><key2><key21>value</key><key22>value</key><key23><key231>value</key></key></key2></data><xml>` output `[data:[key: value, key2: [key21: value, key22: value, key23:[key231: value]]]]`

Comment: I just need to get this map: `[data:[key: value, key2: [key21: value, key22: value, key23:[key231: value]]]]`

Comment: put those please into you original question, so it's a bit more readable

Comment: I update my post

Comment: I don't entirely follow what you're trying to do, but this appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883223/xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map if you're just trying to parse your XML into a map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XmlSlurper to return all xml elements into a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883223/xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map)

Comment: `Map.put` expects two parameters, you are only passing one parameter. Are you instead looking for `Map.putAll`?

Answer (score 0):

I would put it to something like:

```
import groovy.util.*
import groovy.json.*


def text = '''<xml>
<data>
  <key>value1</key>
    <key2>
      <key21>value21</key21>
      <key22>value22</key22>
      <key23>
        <key231>value</key231>
      </key23>
   </key2>
</data>
</xml>'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText( text )

def handle
handle = { node ->
  if( node in String )
    node
  else{
    def val = node.collect handle
    [ (node.name()):1 == val.size() ? val.first() : val.collectEntries{ it } ]
  }
}

def map = xml.collect handle

// this line is needed for pretty print only
JsonOutput.prettyPrint JsonOutput.toJson( map )
```

outputs:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "key": "value1",
            "key2": {
                "key21": "value21",
                "key22": "value22",
                "key23": {
                    "key231": "value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was good for me
`nodeMap[(rootNodeName)] << data`