# Groovy xml to map grouping duplicate keys

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, converters, xmlslurper

I have a xml response and i want it to be converted to a map but some xml nodes are **duplicate** so i want those to be converted to **List of maps**.
Currently I'm using this code suggested in this post :
[xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883223/xmlslurper-to-return-all-xml-elements-into-a-map)

Thanks in advance.

Sample :

```
<head>test</head>
<tail>
    <name>1</name>
    <name>2</name>
</tail>
</body>
```

and I want the following map :

```
["head" : "test" , "tail" : [["name":"1"],["name":"2"]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggling I wrote this code to solve my problem, I tried to use MultiValueMap either but it was converting all the values to list so Finally I had to write in on my own :

```
def xml = new groovy.xml.XmlSlurper().parse(response)
convertToMap(xml)

    def convertToMap(nodes) {
        def map = [:]
        nodes?.children()?.each {
            def key = it.name()
            def value = it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text()
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                def currentValue = map.get(key)
                if (currentValue instanceof List) {
                    currentValue.add(value)
                } else {
                    map.put(key, [currentValue, value])
                }
            } else {
                map.put(key, value)
            }
        }
        map
    }
```

Comment: Great! The only thing is that this code doesn't produce the exact result that you wanted. For me it's: `[head:test, tail:[name:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]`, and you wanted `["head" : "test" , "tail" : [["name":"1"],["name":"2"]]]`. But you're the topic starter, so nice if it works for you :) Also, I'm not sure about `XmlSlurper`. Isn't it from `groovy.xml` package? Not from `groovy.util`, as you say.

Comment: And Yes you are right I wanted [head:test, tail:[name:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]] instead of ["head" : "test" , "tail" : [["name":"1"],["name":"2"]]] and i will change it now. @AndrejIstomin

Comment: Actually I'm working with grails so I think my library is groovy.util. but thanks anyway. And thank you for cooperating.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this piece of code:

```
nodes.children().collectEntries { 
    [it.name(), it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text() ] 
}
```

overrides the value in the resulting map. I didn't manage to find an elegant solution to it without doing some ugly hacks. But here is my solution:

```
final xml = """
<body>
<head>test</head>
<test>
<child>Child</child>
</test>
<tail>
<name>1</name>
<name>2</name>
<name>3</name>
<name>4</name>
<name>5</name>
</tail>
</body>
"""

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
println convertToMap(slurper)

def convertToMap(nodes) {
    final list = []
    final children = nodes.children().iterator()
    while (children.hasNext()) {
        final child = children.next()
        list << [(child.name()): child.childNodes() ? convertToMap(child) : child.text()]
    }
    final keys = list.collect { it.keySet()[0].toString() }
    if (keys.size() == keys.unique().size()) {
        list.collectEntries { [(it.keySet()[0]): it[it.keySet()[0]]] }
    } else {
        list
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is that I first collect all the children as list of map entries, so it looks like `[[key1:value1], [key2:value2]]`. Then I loop over this intermediate structure and gather the results.

I hope it helps to move forward. Maybe later someone will come to you with a better solution, because as I said, at the moment I haven't found any elegant way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. actually there is collection called MultiValueMap I'm considering to use that. because automatically it will add duplicate key values in a list. it converts the value from object to list of object. but now I'm getting NullpointerException in the recursive loop. Thanks again. it really took your time. appreciate it